Sign-off Author field erases itself on commit in JetBrains Rider
In JetBrains Rider (and other JetBrains products) we can Sign Off our commits:

However, after a commit and a push, the Author field erases itself.
Note that everything works as expected on remote. It's just that locally I have to re-write the Author field.
I am connected to GitHub when I got to "Settings > Version Control > GitHub", no issue from there.
I have the same problem with PyCharm. I assume I have something not configured properly across all JetBrains products.
How can I do to have the field not erase itself after each commit? Right now, I have to fill it manually every time I commit.

The title asks one thing and the body something else. Which one is it?

I'm sorry, the body was right. I'll fix the title. Apologies.

Sign-off or author field, which one is it?

author field, sign-off is a checkbox

I assume you've set your git username? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#git-username

Yes that was set up well and I just checked it still is set up.

Given this is specific to the IDE and not to a coding question, I suggest that you refer to Jetbrains support team. This could be a configuration issue or a bug in the application, and they have a dedicated support team that is more knowledgeable than us that can help you with the issue. https://www.jetbrains.com/support/

@MarcSances brillant idea, thank you, I'm sending them an email!

Hi,
This is intended behavior in case you want to sign off specific commits with another name/email.
By default, the signoff option will remain on, and the author name from your git config will be used.
Why do you need to manually input the author name here since it will be automatically picked from your git config?

@DinoLetic It doesn't seem to be picked from my git config though? git config user.email and git config user.name are both filled in (I look at them with the terminal) and nothing appears in Rider/PyCHarm
